# How is using Lua in a Context document different or easier than using Lua in Lualatex document?

Tags: luatex, context, lua

I was reading that context is written mainly using Lua internally.

So I was wondering if this means using Lua in a Context document will be much simpler than using Lua in LuaLatex?  I assumes the interface will be easier there?

Since I prefer Lua to Latex as a language (much easier to read and understand), I thought if using Lua in Context document will be much easier than doing the same in Lualatex document, then this will be an advantage to using Context more.

Since I know very little about Context, here is an example using Lua inside Lualatex. I was wondering how this example will look like in a Context document.

But feel free to provide your example if you think it will be better illustrate the advantage/ease of using Lua on Context vs. in Lualatex.

This example uses Lua to reduce a fraction to lowest common terms.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
%------------------------
\begin{luacode}
function simplify(a,b)     
  local function gcd(a,b)   
    if b ~= 0 then
        return gcd(b, a % b)
    else
        return math.abs(a)
    end
  end

  t = gcd(a, b)
  tex.print("\\frac{"..a//t.."}{"..b//t.."}")
end    
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\simplify[2]{\directlua{simplify(#1,#2) }}%
%-------------------    
\begin{document}    
Can I make \LaTeX{} reduce a fraction automatically?

For example, I would like the fraction
%
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{278\,922}{74\,088}
\end{equation*}
%
to be reduced to
%
\begin{equation*}
  \simplify{278922}{74088}
\end{equation*}    
\end{document}
```

Compiling with Lualatex gives

[image]

How would this code look like in a Context document? Are there things that one can do using Lua inside a Context document that can not be done inside a Lualatex document? Or things that are much easier to do using Lua in a Context document vs. doing the same thing in Lualatex docuemnt?

TL 2023

Comment: I’m wondering how we measure ‘better’ here as the Lua will be the same, and that’s most of the work

Comment: @JosephWright I mean if the interface between the Tex and Lua is easier or more seamless in Context vs. Lualatex or it is the same. I know the Lua code in this example will be the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not really an answer, but too long for a comment. I happened to be in contact with Hans when reading this question, and he then sent me the following, so this is how it could look I guess:

```
\startluacode
     local abs   = math.abs
     local round = math.round

     local function gcd(a,b)
         return b ~= 0 and gcd(b,a%b) or abs(a)
     end

     interfaces.implement {
         name      = "Sfrac",
         arguments = "2 strings",
         public    = true,
         actions   = function(a,b)
             local t = gcd(a,b)
             context.frac(round(a//t),round(b//t))
         end
     }
\stopluacode

\setupmathematics[autopunctuation=comma]

\starttext

\samplefile{knuthmath}

\startformula
     \frac{278,922}{74,088}
     =
     \Sfrac{278922}{74088}
\stopformula

\samplefile{knuthmath}

\stoptext
```

[image: output]

I am not the right person to analyze coding styles and efficiency or things like that, so I leave that to others, but let me mention some things:

After collaborating for almost two years with Hans, mainly on typesetting of math, but also on several other parts, I have seen *a lot* of code he has written, both C, lua and tex (cod that is part of the luametatex engine, and the ConTeXt system). My impression is that he makes a very strong point in writing *clean and optimized code*. ConTeXt has come in different versions depending on the development of engines (mkii for pdftex), (mkiv for luatex) and (mkxl for luametatex), and that has probably simplified a lot during the years, since it has made it possible to concentrate the work on one engine at a time. For the current version, it has not hurt that he has been developing the luametatex engine in parallel with ConTeXt lmtx (as with luatex and ConTeXt mkiv, and correct me if I am wrong, but perhaps he was also a bit involved when the pdftex engine was created and mkii was developed). The point is that he has an extremely good and unique overview of the whole combined system, and therefore knows where to put the effort. He simply controls both the engine and the macro package, and can make decisions thereafter. That of course does not show or imply that ConTeXt has a better support for lua (after all, both systems can run lua), but I think that one should be aware that the fact that lua was there all along the way likely have implications.

Somebody else has to give details about how the lua part of luaLaTeX has evolved and show good examples.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to add a different level of abstraction than mickep. His example nicely illustrates planned interfaces from Lua to TeX and how you properly define commands from the Lua end. My answer will focus on ad-hoc usage in the document which may or may not be what you want but is what I use quite often and enjoy using in ConTeXt.

Consider the following document (and yes, it is ad-hoc, so that's exactly the point I want to make):

```
\starttext
\startluacode
context.startxtable()
context.startxtablebody()

for i,t in ipairs({"test", "test 2", "test 3"}) do
  context.startxrow()

  for j,v in ipairs({i, t, "col 3", "col 4"}) do
    context.startxcell()
    context(v)
    context.stopxcell()
  end
  context.stopxrow()
end

context.stopxtablebody()
context.stopxtable()

-- example for passing arguments from https://wiki.contextgarden.net/CLD

context.placefigure(
    "none",
    function()
        context.framed( {
            frame="on",
            align="middle"
        },  
            function() context.input("knuth") end 
        )   
    end 
)

context.par()
\stopluacode
\stoptext
```

The first part of the code illustrates creating a table from loops. In LuaLaTeX I continuously struggled to do this properly because I never managed to escape the values correctly or didn't `tex.print` the right things, especially with respect to table handling and cells.

Furthermore, this also illustrates that you can access all regular ConTeXt TeX commands from the `context` table/namespace, e.g. `context.startxtable()` for `\startxtable` etc. In that way, you don't have escaped commands in printouts sprinkled around but it looks and feels like Lua (although my code is not idiomatic Lua).

The second part I copied from the ConTeXt wiki for ConTeXt Lua Documents. It illustrates how you can manage advanced commands from Lua (or even add arguments; you could add arguments the same way for the xtable before). Especially notice how the optional arguments in `\framed[frame=on, align=middle]{\input{knuth}}` map nicely to a Lua table (`{frame="on", align="middle"}`) and you can use an arbitrary function to output anything within the actual frame.

As a summary of my personal opinion: yes, using Lua in ConTeXt is much more natural and even easier than in LuaLaTeX. And yes, I have even built complete ConTeXt documents that read like Lua instead of TeX. It's possible and sometimes enjoyable and the right tool for the job.

---

ps. Hope it is OK that I edited this answer to add screen shot of the above code output. Compiled using `context foo.tex` on TL 2023.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the link [https://wiki.contextgarden.net/CLD](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/CLD) I wish the page have many more examples though, as I think this is very useful feature of context, and could be a major selling point to using Context as I also find programming in Lua much easier than coding in Latex syntax. May be some context/lua expert could help add many more examples to this wiki page in the future. Most users learn by looking at examples.

Comment: There are more examples at [https://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/cld-mkiv.pdf](https://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/cld-mkiv.pdf)  see **6.2 The LUA interface** and **5 Some more examples**